# How to do the GET method from a hashmap with objects?

Tags: java

Im trying to get the id of a posto from an hashmap to compare the value in another class:

My class Posto:

```
public class Posto {

    private int id;
    private Point posicao;
    private int capacidade;
    private int quantidadeAtual;
    private int gastoMedio;


    public Posto(int id, Point posicao, int capacidade, int quantidadeAtual, int gastoMedio) {

        this.id = id;
        this.posicao = posicao;
        this.capacidade = capacidade;
        this.quantidadeAtual = quantidadeAtual;
        this.gastoMedio = gastoMedio;

    }


    public int getPostoId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setPostoId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    public Point getPostoPosicao() {
        return posicao;
    }
    public void setPostoPosicao(Point posicao) {
        this.posicao = posicao;
    }



    public int getPostoCapacidade() {
        return capacidade;
    }
    public void setPostoCapacidade(int capacidade) {
        this.capacidade = capacidade;
    }



    public int getPostoQuantidadeAtual() {
        return quantidadeAtual;
    }
    public void setPostoQuantidadeAtual(int quantidadeAtual) {
        this.quantidadeAtual = quantidadeAtual;
    }



    public int getPostoGastoMedio() {
        return gastoMedio;
    }
    public void setPostoGastoMedio(int gastoMedio) {
        this.gastoMedio = gastoMedio;
    }
```

My MAIN class where i fill the hashmaps like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Central c = new Central( new Point(20, 300) );

        setupCentral( c );

        MenuCentral mc = new MenuCentral( c );
        mc.menuPrincipal();


    }

    private static void setupCentral(Central c) {

        //Posto p1 = new Posto(1,new Point(2,3),24,40,30);

        c.addPosto(new Posto(1,new Point(10,10),10,200,180));
        c.addPosto(new Posto(2,new Point(700,15),15,300,200));

    }

}
```

And now my CENTRAL class where i have the method "addPosto" to fill the hashmap and i need the method "getPosto" to get the ids to compare in other class but i can't do it, i'm a little bit confused about the hashmaps.

```
    public class Central {

        private Point posicao;
        private Map<Integer, Object> camioes = new HashMap<Integer,Object>( );
        private Map<Integer,Object> postos = new HashMap<Integer,Object>( );

        public Central(Point posicao) {
            this.posicao = posicao;
        }

        public Point getPosicao() {
            return posicao;
        }

        public void setPosicao(Point posicao) {
            this.posicao = posicao;
        }


        public void addPosto( Posto p ){
            postos.put(p.getPostoId(), p);
        }


        ***public int getPosto (int id){
        }***

    }
```

Comment: Just call `get` on the map: `return postos.get(id);`

Comment: Do you want to get the `Posto` instance that belongs to that ID? Or do you want to verify that `ID` exists in your list? Or do you want to get the ID based on something else?

Comment: I want to verify if the id exists or not.

Comment: To verify if the map has an entry with the specified id: `postos.containsKey(id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Map has only one value type.

```
private final Map<Integer, Posto> postos = new HashMap<>();
```

And you only add this type.

```
public void addPosto( Posto p ){
    postos.put(p.getPostoId(), p);
}
```

so it makes sense to expect this type.

```
 public Posto getPosto(int id) {
     return postos.get(id);
 }
```

If you want to leave the Map as it is (which is a bad idea IMHO you can use an explicit cast)

```
 public Posto getPosto(int id) {
     return (Posto) postos.get(id);
 }
```

This is needlessly verbose and error prone.  At some point doing this will almost certainly lead to a bug which never needed to happen.

Comment: i already tried that but the get() method from hashmap postos only returns object. ERROR: Type mismatch : cannot convert from Object to int

Comment: @JohnOak In that case, I suggest you read the second line of my answer again. If you want the values to be `Posto` and not `Object` I suggest you make them `Posto` instead.

Comment: yes, but is there a way to do it without chaging the hashmap? maybe if i fill them in a diferent way?

Comment: @JohnOak I have updated my answer, and while you can do do this, you shouldn't.

Comment: Hmm i see, u're right. Thanks, it's working both ways

Answer (score 0):

```
public Posto getPosto (int id)
{
    return postos.get(id);
}
```

Comment: ERROR: Type mismatch : cannot convert from Object to int

Comment: Yeah man i wrote int there instead Posto i already changed it , forgive me

Comment: Already tried that too, it just keep giving me errors. "Cannot convert from Object to Porto."

Answer (score 0):

sice you are adding posto class to the hashmap use generics

```
 private Map<Integer, Posto> camioes = new HashMap<Integer,Posto>( );
    private Map<Integer,Posto> postos = new HashMap<Integer,Posto>( );

you can iterate the hashmap and get all the values 

for (Integer key : camioes.keySet()) {
     Posto p = postos.get(key);
        System.out.println(p.getPostoId());
}
}
```